# Error in count/group by for query inside another query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

I'm trying to extract the total number of ratings published in a specific year from this database:
[image: db]

This is the code I entered to extract this number:

```
SELECT Count(*) NrOfRatings
FROM (SELECT timestamp, FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) as datetime, 
CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) as date) AS date_value 
FROM ratings
WHERE year(CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) as date) )=2000) NrOfRatings
GROUP BY NrOfRatings;
```

I think the problem comes from the function `GROUP BY` linked to the count function. I tried grouping by `movieId`, `timestamp` and others but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please share the expected output for above dataset

Comment: You haven't actually stated what the error is that you are seeing, but in any case your SQL is much more complicated than it needs to be. All you need to do use is (pseudo-code not actual SQL): select count(1) from table where year(timestamp) = 2000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping on the count function wasn't needed.
One would group by what's not in an aggregation function like COUNT, MIN, MAX, AVG, ...

For example, grouping by the calculated year

```
select 
 year(from_unixtime(`timestamp`)) as `year`, 
 count(*) as NrOfRatings
from ratings
where year(from_unixtime(`timestamp`)) = 2000
group by `year`
```

**Extra:**

To query on more years use `IN`:

```
where year(from_unixtime(`timestamp`)) IN (2000,2002,2004)
```

Or a `BETWEEN` for a range:

```
where year(from_unixtime(`timestamp`)) BETWEEN 2000 AND 2020
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is count of number of ratings for same year occurring in multiple rows to be grouped and get the count of rating.

If you want it to be just for one specific year than you can do as below

`select count(1) from Ratings where year(CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) as date))=2000`

But if you want to know count of ratings for every set of years than you need to partition your data based on year and than just count over it.

```
SELECT *,year(CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) as date)) as yearForTimeStamp,
COUNT(*) Over(Partition by year(CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) as date))) as
NoOfRating 
FROM Ratings
```

[Running query with example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qoEFvCcGL4inPDGdgYf5gA/0)